# generate an ISO date from a pre-existing field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Is there a quicker way to do this?  From what I understand it cannot be done in a projection using the aggregation pipeline.  Do I *have* to pre-calculate this?  I basically want to emit part of the date (i.e. an hour) in a map function (for a map-reduce).  I appreciate you taking the time to help me :-)

```
db.events.find().snapshot().forEach( 
    function (e) { 
        e.StartTime = new Date(e.start_time); 
        db.events.save(e); 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) is the fastest "safe" way to do this:

```js
var bulk = db.events.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.events.find({ },{ "start_time": 1 }).snapshot().forEach(function(e) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": e._id }).updateOne({ 
       "$set": { "StartTime": new Date(e.start_time) }
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.events.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

That will only send and return from the server once per every 1000 documents read. So the decreased traffic there saves a lot of time, as does working with only the required fields.

If this is absolutely a "one off" operation that does not need to continue to happen in production, and if you are able to do so then you can always use [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/). But please read the documentation and warnings there as it is not a very good idea:

```js
db.eval(function() {
    db.events.find({ },{ "start_time": 1 }).snapshot().forEach(function(e) {
        db.events.update(
           { "_id": e._id },
           { "$set": { "StartTime": new Date(e.start_time) } }
    });
]);
```

But if you are looking for any other way to "convert" a field, there is presently no way for an update operation to refer to an existing value of a field and use it to update another, or even itself. There are exceptions such as `$inc` or `$bit`, but these have specific purposes.

Comment: Neil, I apologize it took a while for me to get back to you.  This is exactly the answer I needed.  It appears that the last two lines of your first code block are not necessary.  I am assuming this is a simple error.  Thank you for your help (again).

Comment: @dps The last two lines exist as since the operation is executed on the modulo of the current count matching 1000 ( therefore 1000 items at a time ) then any number that is not exactly a divisor of 1000 would be excluded. So this "catches" the cases where only 600 items are processed or 10,421 items are processed, since neither are exactly divisible by 1000 and the remainder is then processed. So not an error but required logic.